# Angular CDK: How to set Inputs in a ComponentPortal

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-cdk

I would like to use the new [Portal](https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/overview) from material CDK to inject dynamic content in multiple part of a form.

I have a complex form structure and the goal is to have a form that specify multiple place where sub components could (or not) inject templates.

Maybe the CDK Portal is not the best solution for this?

I tried something but I am sure it is not the way of doing: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yuz1kg

I tried also with `new ComponentPortal(MyPortalComponent)` but how can we set Inputs on it ? Usually is something like `componentRef.component.instance.myInput`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can create a custom injector and inject it to the component portal you create.

```ts
createInjector(dataToPass): PortalInjector {
    const injectorTokens = new WeakMap();
    injectorTokens.set(CONTAINER_DATA, dataToPass);
    return new PortalInjector(this._injector, injectorTokens);
}
```

`CONTAINER_DATA` is a custom injector (`InjectorToken`) created by -

```ts
export const CONTAINER_DATA = new InjectionToken<{}>('CONTAINER_DATA');
```

To consume created injector, use -

```ts
let containerPortal = new ComponentPortal(ComponentToPort, null, this.createInjector({
          data1,
          data2
        }));

overlay.attach(containerPortal);
```

`overlay` is an instance of `OverlayRef` (Which is Portal Outlet)

Inside `ComponentToPort`, you will need to inject the created injector -

```ts
@Inject(CONTAINER_DATA) public componentData: any
```

More on this [here](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/8322).

Comment: When I try to do this I get the following:

Can't resolve all parameters for ComponentToPort: ([object Object], [object Object], ?).

Where the ? is the CONTAINER_DATA

Comment: Probably inside 'ComponentToPort', you will need to import CONTAINER_DATA from the location you created it. That might resolve the issue.

Comment: Is this actually the only way to accomplish this? The problem with using injected tokens is you aren't afforded any kind of change detection – no `ngOnChanges`, no `async | pipe`, nada. 

Short of passing in an Observable as the token, it seems you're left with a purely static value. Is this really the case, there's there's no way to leverage `@Input`s?

Comment: what about @output?

Comment: @wosevision 
Perhaps by using a template portal instead of a component portal. You can bind inputs and outputs in a template and then just use the overlay library to position it.

Comment: You need to declare the injected componentData in the constructor of the ComponentToPort `constructor(@Inject(CONTAINER_DATA) public componentData: any ) {}`

Comment: What about `ngContent`? If my `ComponentToPort` has a `<ng-content>` how do I pass data to it?

Comment: @muuvmuuv maybe you'd have to pass another portal in instead of ng-content?

Comment: PortalInjector is deprecated now. It seems that Injector.create is recommended instead.

Comment: And we can use Material elements in the `ComponentToPort` ? Say a `<mat-icon>` ?

Answer (score 46):

If you are using Angular 10+ and following [Awadhoot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48074678/2582581), PortalInjector is now deprecated so instead of:

```
new PortalInjector(this.injector, new WeakMap([[SOME_TOKEN, data]]))
```

You now have:

```
Injector.create({
  parent: this.injector,
  providers: [
    { provide: SOME_TOKEN, useValue: data }
  ]
})
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for with the deprecation of PortalInjector

Answer (score 38):

Can set component inputs (or bind to outputs as an observable) in this way:

```
portal = new ComponentPortal(MyComponent);
this.portalHost = new DomPortalHost(
      this.elementRef.nativeElement,
      this.componentFactoryResolver,
      this.appRef,
      this.injector
    );

const componentRef = this.portalHost.attach(this.portal);
componentRef.instance.myInput = data;
componentRef.instance.myOutput.subscribe(...);
componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
```

Comment: a much easier solution than the other answers, at least for me !

Comment: indeed so much easier than creating a custom injector !

Comment: best answer, the injector way makes you write components in a non "standard" way and has limitations

Comment: So is this sort of bypassing the proper `@Input()` mechanism, and/or does it matter since you explicitly call `detectChanges` - or is that the whole point :-)

Comment: This has a huge advantage besides simplicity, it allows you to make the component agnostic about the overlay. A potential downside is that it might execute `ngOnInit` before the inputs are set (didn't check this yet).

Comment: This is the best solution so far, but be aware that `ngOnChanges` does not get called

Comment: Addition to my comment above: here is the github issue for adding an API to set inputs https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22567

Comment: This won't work if the portal host is abstracted away from where you construct the portal, for example if you are passing them to a service or the like.

Answer (score 21):

this seems a bit more simple, using the cdkPortalOutlet and the (attached) emitter

```js
    import {Component, ComponentRef, AfterViewInit, TemplateRef, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
    import {ComponentPortal, CdkPortalOutletAttachedRef, Portal, TemplatePortal, CdkPortalOutlet} from '@angular/cdk/portal';
    
    /**
     * @title Portal overview
     */
    @Component({
      selector: 'cdk-portal-overview-example',
      template: '<ng-template [cdkPortalOutlet]="componentPortal" (attached)=foo($event)></ng-template>',
      styleUrls: ['cdk-portal-overview-example.css'],
    })
    export class CdkPortalOverviewExample implements OnInit {
      componentPortal: ComponentPortal<ComponentPortalExample>;
    
      constructor(private _viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {}
    
      ngOnInit() {
        this.componentPortal = new ComponentPortal(ComponentPortalExample);
      }
    
      foo(ref: CdkPortalOutletAttachedRef) {
        ref = ref as ComponentRef<ComponentPortalExample>;
        ref.instance.message = 'zap';
      }
    }
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'component-portal-example',
      template: 'Hello, this is a component portal {{message}}'
    })
    export class ComponentPortalExample {
      @Input() message: string;
    }
```

Comment: there's also an @output() that emits the ref, see:
https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/cdk/portal/portal-directives.ts

Comment: This is really a very good soltution for the given problem. I have tried all which mentioned above but this one is the smallest and found best solution to pass data into component portals.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  The OP wanted to get a ref to the dynamically created component instance and call methods on it.  Using the `attached` event is the right way to do that.

Comment: I tried many many things, only this worked thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You can inject data to `ComponentPortal` with specific injector passed on **3rd param** of `ComponentPortal`

**fix syntax issue**:

```
Can't resolve all parameters for Component: ([object Object], [object Object], ?
```

This is the code

```
export const PORTAL_DATA = new InjectionToken<{}>('PortalData');

class ContainerComponent {
  constructor(private injector: Injector, private overlay: Overlay) {}

  attachPortal() {
    const componentPortal = new ComponentPortal(
      ComponentToPort,
      null,
      this.createInjector({id: 'first-data'})
    );
    this.overlay.create().attach(componentPortal);
  }

  private createInjector(data): PortalInjector {

    const injectorTokens = new WeakMap<any, any>([
      [PORTAL_DATA, data],
    ]);

    return new PortalInjector(this.injector, injectorTokens);
  }
}

class ComponentToPort {
  constructor(@Inject(PORTAL_DATA) public data ) {
    console.log(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to explain the code as well why this will work

Answer (score 5):

After version angular 9 'DomPortalHost' has been deprecated and this has been changed to 'DomPortalOutlet'. so now it will like:

```
this.portalHost = new DomPortalOutlet(
   this.elementRef.nativeElement,
   this.componentFactoryResolver,
   this.appRef,
  this.injector
);
```

`const componentRef = this.portalHost.attachComponentPortal(this.portal);
componentRef.instance.myInput = data;`

Apart from this I felt the best solution for this is just bind the (attached) event and set inputs there:

`<ng-template [cdkPortalOutlet]="yourPortal" (attached)="setInputs($event)"> </ng-template>`

and in ts set your inputs:

```
setInputs(portalOutletRef: CdkPortalOutletAttachedRef) {
    portalOutletRef = portalOutletRef as ComponentRef<myComponent>;
    portalOutletRef.instance.inputPropertyName = data;
}
```

Comment: Note: The description for `DomPortalOutlet` is `"A PortalOutlet for attaching portals to an arbitrary DOM element outside of the Angular application context."` - So it's really intended for putting some Angular component on a completely random element on your page. If you're using Angular alone you probably want `ng-template` approach (as you showed above).

Comment: If anyone is trying to put something outside of the Angular context then also check out Angular Elements (https://angular.io/guide/elements).

Answer (score 5):

I know, the question is 4 years old, but maybe helpful for someone:
In current version of CDK the ComponentPortal has a new function named "setInput":

```
setInputs(portalOutletRef: CdkPortalOutletAttachedRef) {
portalOutletRef = portalOutletRef as ComponentRef<BaseAuditView>;

portalOutletRef.setInput('prop1', this.prop1);
portalOutletRef.setInput('prop2', this.prop2);
```

}

if you using this function, angular`s change detections works very well!

> (method) ComponentRef.setInput(name: string, value: unknown): void
> Updates a specified input name to a new value. Using this method will properly mark for check component using the OnPush change detection strategy. It will also assure that the OnChanges lifecycle hook runs when a dynamically created component is change-detected.

@param name — The name of an input.

@param value — The new value of an input.

Answer (score 2):

No idea from what version of Angular this is working (at least from 13.3.9). But there is a much simpler way now because `overlayRef.attach(portal)` is now returning `ComponentRef`.
So

```
    const overlayRef = this._overlay.create();
    const portal = new ComponentPortal(MyComponent);
    const cmpRef = overlayRef.attach(portal);
    cmpRef.instance.myInput = 42;
```

will work now

Comment: this doesn't trigger ngOnChanges unfortunately

Comment: You can do it manually `cmpRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();`