# Passing data to and from a ComponentPortal in Angular CDK

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cdk

I have tried to use the method found at [Angular CDK: How to set Inputs in a ComponentPortal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47469844/angular-cdk-how-to-set-inputs-in-a-componentportal)
but `PortalInjector` seems to be deprecated, with no actual instructions on what to do in its place. The deprecation warning states to "Use `Injector.create` instead." with but not how or where to use it or what it's actually replacing.

I have also tried to wrap my head around [Material's own Dialog component](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/97ec228ada31e55f76a7e0171c715bb0b8d07e9c/src/material/dialog/dialog.ts#L313) to see if I could figure out how they did it, but nothing.

**So I pose the question again for Angular 13**:

How can I pass data into and out of a component that was created using a `ComponentPortal()`? If the answer is something generic such as using an Injector, can you please point me to an example or documentation on how to do so? A 'hello world' of passing Injectors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMHO, we do not have a straightforward way to have something that we do as an Input or Output from `componentportal`.

What you can do is to pass the data which you want to use as `@Input` using the `attached` event of portal.

[Check this demo code where we are passing value to Guest component](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cdk-component-portal-bqxgso?file=src%2Fapp%2Fguest%2Fguest.component.html).

```
<ng-template (attached)="onComponentRendering($event)" [cdkPortalOutlet]="guestPortal"></ng-template>
```

and then using it as

```
 public onComponentRendering(ref): void {
    ref = ref as ComponentRef<any>;
    ref.instance['guestData'] = [ ...something];
 }
```

For output data, you can create a service (with [Subject](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject)) and use it to communicate between components.

Answer (score 11):

Obviously I am late to the party, but you can actually use `@Input()` and `@Output()` of the component displayed inside a Portal. It is not obvious on the first sight, but calling `this.overlayRef.attach(MyComponent)` will return `ComponentRef<MyComponent>`. So from that you can quite easily get direct access to the component instance, and then do whatever you need with it.

Like this:

```
const componentPortal = new ComponentPortal(MyComponent);
const componentRef = this.overlayRef.attach(componentPortal);

// pass data via Input:
componentRef.instance.someInput = 'test';

// subscribe to output:
componentRef.instance.someOutput.subsribe();
```

And the MyComponent would look like this:

```
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent {
    @Input()
    someInput: string;

    @Output()
    someOutput = new EventEmitter<string>();
}
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Nobody late at party :). Furthermore, your solution is for me the good solution

Comment: Wow, I wish I had know about this a few projects ago. This is a great solution and now I can just use one overlay and pass the display text in as an Input. Thank you!

Comment: I don't get it what is overlayRef and where does it come from? Can you please add more information?

Comment: Was lost as well:

"The overlay package provides a way to open floating panels on the screen."

- https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview

Answer (score 7):

I'm a little late to the party but here's another option actually using `Injector.create`.

First I defined an injection token:

```
export const DATA_INJECTION_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<string>('DATA_INJECTION_TOKEN');
```

In my case I have a service that handles creating and providing the `ComponentPortal`. Which looks something like this:

```
export class FooService {
  // ...

  open(component: ComponentType<any>, data?: unknown) {
    // ...

    const portal = new ComponentPortal(
      component,
      null,
      Injector.create({
        providers: [{ provide: DATA_INJECTION_TOKEN, useValue: data }],
      }),
    );

    // ...
  }
}
```

Then used `@Inject()` to retrieve the data.

```
export class FoobarComponent {
  constructor(@Inject(DATA_INJECTION_TOKEN) data: MyDataType) { }
}
```

And finally when calling the service that to generate the portal it looked like this:

```
const data = {foo: 'bar'};
fooService.open(FoobarComponent, data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used another little bit different approach. Especially for small data this is reasonable. I couldn't use the suggested approach from @Shashank Vivek because I initiated the `ComponentPortal` in a `directive`.

You can use `ReplaySubject`. e.g. (as a very rough sketch). First define in an `Injectable`

```
@Injectable
myService {
  overlayNotification: ReplaySubject<boolean>;
}
```

in your `Component`

```
myComponent  implements OnInit
constructor(private myService:myService){}
ngOnInit() {
  this.myService.overlayNotification=new ReplaySubject();
}
method4Overlay(){
  this.myService.overlayNotification.next(.... your data ...);
  this.overlayRef = this.overlay.create(overlayConfig);
  this.overlayRef.attach(new ComponentPortal(MySampleComponent));
}
```

and last but not least in your `MySampleComponent`

```
MySampleComponent implements OnInit
constructor(private myService:myService){}
ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.overlayNotification.subscribe((myData:...) => .... received data);
 }
```

So you can simply update with the `ReplaySubject`. The `ReplaySubject` has as well the advantage that you don't need to care when the `init` for `MySampleComponent` runs. It emits the event independently from the order or `init`. Which is as well a disadvantage since you need to create it as a new one - i.e. the events are not fired again.

I think you need to code the details on your own. But this rough sketch gives you an idea of another way to circumvent `@Input()` (in general).